# Build JPA Specification from tree

Tags: java, algorithm, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I have created an API which allows users to build out queries using a tree. The tree is built from the `SearchOperationRequest` class.

```
@Data
@ApiModel(value = "SearchOperationRequest", description = "Condition for the query")
public class SearchOperationRequest {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Conditional statement for the where clause", allowableValues = "EQUALS, NOT_EQUALS, GREATER_THAN, LESS_THAN, LIKE, STARTS_WITH, ENDS_WITH, CONTAINS")
    private SearchConditionOperation condition;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Column name to be searched on")
    private String column;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Value of column")
    private Object value;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Value of OR / AND")
    private SearchComparator comparator;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Left node of comparator condition")
    private SearchOperationRequest left;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Right node of comparator condition")
    private SearchOperationRequest right;

    public boolean isTreeLeaf() {
        return left == null && right == null;
    }

    public boolean isComparator() {
        return comparator != null;
    }
}
```

So from this example I could create a `SearchOperationRequest` that asks for all **WHERE hidden = false AND X = 88**

```
"searchOperation": {
    "left": {
        "column": "Hidden",
        "condition": "EQUALS",
        "value": false
    },
    "comparator": "AND",
    "right": {
        "left": {
            "column": "X",
            "condition": "EQUALS",
            "value": 88
        },
        "comparator": "AND"
    }
}
```

This request is built into a specification using a generic specification builder.

```
public class GenericSpecificationsBuilder<U> {

    public Specification<U> buildSpecificationFromSearchOperationRequest(SearchOperationRequest root, Function<SpecificationSearchCriteria, Specification<U>> converter) {

        Stack<SearchOperationRequest> stack = new Stack<>();

        Stack<SearchOperationRequest> comparatorStack = new Stack<>();
        Deque<Specification<U>> specStack = new LinkedList<>();

        SearchOperationRequest pointer = root;

        while (pointer != null || !stack.empty()) {

            if (pointer.isTreeLeaf()) {
                specStack.push(converter.apply(new SpecificationSearchCriteria(pointer.getColumn(), pointer.getCondition(), pointer.getValue())));
            }

            if (pointer.isComparator()) {
                comparatorStack.push(pointer);
            }

            if (pointer.getRight() != null) {
                stack.push(pointer.getRight());
            }

            if (pointer.getLeft() != null) {
                pointer.setRight(pointer.getLeft());
                pointer.setLeft(null);
            } else if (!stack.empty()) {
                SearchOperationRequest temp = stack.pop();
                pointer.setRight(temp);
            }

            pointer = pointer.getRight();
        }


        while (specStack.size() <= comparatorStack.size()) {
            comparatorStack.pop();
        }

        while (!comparatorStack.empty()) {

            SearchOperationRequest searchOperationRequest = comparatorStack.pop();

            Specification<U> operand1 = specStack.pop();
            Specification<U> operand2 = specStack.pop();
            if (searchOperationRequest.getComparator().equals(SearchComparator.AND)) {
                specStack.push(Specification.where(operand1)
                        .and(operand2));
            } else if (searchOperationRequest.getComparator().equals(SearchComparator.OR)) {
                specStack.push(Specification.where(operand1)
                        .or(operand2));
            }
        }


        return specStack.pop();
    }
}
```

My current works great for RIGHT heavy tree's. Meaning queries such as:

```
WHERE X = 6 AND X = 9
WHERE Z = 5 OR T=9
WHERE Z = 5 OR T=9 OR H=6
```

But it does not work with building more complex trees where the criteria in braces should get precedence and executed first.

```
WHERE (X = 6 OR Z = 9) AND (T=6 OR H=8)
```

The model for this more complex `SearchOperationRequest` would be:

```
"searchOperation": {
    "left": {
        "left": {
            "column": "X",
            "condition": "EQUALS",
            "value": 6
        },
        "comparator": "AND",
        "right": {
            "column": "Z",
            "condition": "EQUALS",
            "value": 9
        }
    },
    "comparator": "AND",
    "right": {
        "left": {
            "column": "T",
            "condition": "EQUALS",
            "value": 6
        },
        "comparator": "AND",
        "right": {
            "column": "H",
            "condition": "EQUALS",
            "value": 8
        }
    }
}
```

How do I modify my `GenericSpecificationsBuilder` to be able to handle more complex `SearchOperationRequest` trees?

Comment: Looks like I didn't put the root `comparator` on the stack, fixed the code. Did you get it to work?

Comment: @ingen First couple of test cases and it is working great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's follow the execution flow using your example tree.

```
         AND
      /       \
  leftOR     rightOR
  /    \     /    \ 
X=6   Z=9  T=6   H=8
```

When we exit the first `while` loop, our stacks look like:

```
stack = {}
comparatorStack = { AND, leftOR, rightOR }
specStack = { X=6, Z=9, T=6, H=8 }
```

The same state enters the final `while` loop.

```
while (!comparatorStack.empty()) {

    SearchOperationRequest searchOperationRequest = comparatorStack.pop();

    Specification<U> operand1 = specStack.pop();
    Specification<U> operand2 = specStack.pop();
    if (searchOperationRequest.getComparator().equals(SearchComparator.AND)) {
        specStack.push(Specification.where(operand1)
                .and(operand2));
    } else if (searchOperationRequest.getComparator().equals(SearchComparator.OR)) {
        specStack.push(Specification.where(operand1)
                .or(operand2));
    }
}
```

The problem here is you're pushing the result back on the `specStack`. So at the second iteration, you'll be popping off the result of the first iteration (the `rightOR`), as well as `Z=9`, and apply the `leftOr` logic to it.

**Decomposing the tree**

Let's take a step back and look at how you decompose the tree, more specifically:

```
if (pointer.getLeft() != null) {
    pointer.setRight(pointer.getLeft());
    pointer.setLeft(null);
} else if (!stack.empty()) {
    SearchOperationRequest temp = stack.pop();
    pointer.setRight(temp);
}
```

The problem with this code is you are altering the nodes in the tree. In the first example, at one time our pointer points to the node:

```
    Z=9      
  /     \ 
null   rightOR
```

That doesn't look right. Instead of decomposing the tree using a stack ([Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)), you could use a queue ([Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)) and get the ordering you're after for free.

[image: BFS]

Does that solve the problem of applying each logical operator (`comparator`) to the right operands? Not quite, to be able to solve both layouts below, we could decompose the operators and operands in different workflows, instead of all of them together.

```
         AND                    |                    rootAND                 
      /       \                 |                  /         \    
  leftOR     rightOR            |              leftOR       rightOR  
  /    \     /    \             |              /    \       /    \   
X=6   Z=9  T=6   H=8            |            X=6    AND    Z=9   H=8   
                                |                 /    \      
                                |               T=6   Y=3
```

**Solution**

The first json-like representation in your post has an illogical layout, as logical operators are expected to operate on both a left and right operand. Instead you had:

```
"right": {
    "left": {
        "column": "X",
        "condition": "EQUALS",
        "value": 88
    },
    "comparator": "AND"
}
```

Let's consider a solution for symmetrical representations, one where both a left and right operand are present for each logical operator.

First we process the tree *Breadth First*, level by level. Meanwhile, we put each `comparator` on a stack, so we get the last ones out first in our second `while` loop.

In the second loop we then use a new `Queue` to store our 'in-between-results' as we work our way back to the root.

```
Queue<SearchOperationRequest> queue = new LinkedList<>();
Deque<SearchOperationRequest> comparatorStack = new LinkedList<>();

if (root == null || !root.isComparator()) return;
queue.add(root);
while(!queue.isEmpty()){
    SearchOperationRequest node = queue.poll();
    comparatorStack.push(node);
    if(node.left != null && node.left.isComparator()) queue.add(node.left);
    if(node.right != null && node.right.isComparator()) queue.add(node.right);
}

Queue<Specification> specQueue = new LinkedList<>();
while(!comparatorStack.isEmpty()){
    SearchOperationRequest comparator = comparatorStack.pop();
    // reverse operand order so already computed values are polled correctly
    Specification operand2; 
    SearchOperationRequest pointer = comparator.getRight();
    if(pointer.isTreeLeaf()) {
        operand2 = converter.apply(new SpecificationSearchCriteria(pointer.getColumn(), pointer.getCondition(), pointer.getValue()));
    } else {
        operand2 = specQueue.poll();
    }
    Specification operand1; 
    pointer = comparator.getLeft();
    if(pointer.isTreeLeaf()) {
        operand1 = converter.apply(new SpecificationSearchCriteria(pointer.getColumn(), pointer.getCondition(), pointer.getValue()));
    } else {
        operand1 = specQueue.poll();
    }
    if (comparator.equals(SearchComparator.AND)) {
        specQueue.add(Specification.where(operand1).and(operand2));
    } else if (comparator.equals(SearchComparator.OR)) {
        specQueue.add(Specification.where(operand1).or(operand2));
    }
} 

return specQueue.poll();
```

I haven't tested the code, but you should be able to extract (and refactor) the workflows.